# Git get line edit time

Tags: git, bash

Good evening.
How to get line edit time in epoch in git?
I used command

```
git blame -t -L line_num,line_num -- file
```

But it brings a lot not needed info
I just want to get one number

Comment: What about grep and awk?

Comment: @Vinny of course I tried to use awk, but epoch time is in 2nd or in 3d place, so the code become bulky a little bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use -p (porcelain) to output in a more computer-friendly format.

You can then pipe into awk to find the parts of the output that you need

```
git blame -p -t -L line_num,line_num -- file | awk '/author-time/ {print $2}'
```

Optionally pipe out to `uniq` if you want to remove duplicates entries.

Source: https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-blame

Comment: Thanks Edmund, you helped a lot! ;)